# Как правильно сравнить два значения в Realm Swift

Tags: swift, парсер, realm

У меня есть база данных `Realm` под названием `NewsCount` . Мне надо скачать новые новости только в том случае если есть новые новости (соответственно когда `newsCount` измениться). И я делаю сравнение при парсинге данных. Но у меня не получается правильно сравнить их. Как их сравнить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код.

```
private func parseJSONData(_ data: Data) {
    do {
        let temp: NSString = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!
        let myNSData = temp.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!

        guard let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: myNSData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary else {
            return
        }
        guard let jsonNews = jsonResult["categories"] as? [AnyObject] else {
            print("Empty array")
            return
        }

        let realm = try Realm()
        let category = realm.objects(NewsCount.self)
        var array = [Int]()

        for i in category {
            array.append(i.newsCount)
        }

        print(array)
        print("News COUNT2 \(category)")

        for jsonnewes in jsonNews {
            let newsJson = NewsCount()

            //ВОТ ЗДЕСЬ Я ДОЛЖЕН СРАВНИТЬ
            if !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "AppStarted") || jsonnewes["count"] as! Int > array[jsonnewes as! Int]{
                newsJson.newsID = jsonnewes["term_id"] as! Int
                newsJson.newsCount = jsonnewes["count"] as! Int
                //print("News COUNT2 \(newsJson.newsCount)")
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "downloadNew"), object: nil)
            } else {
                newsJson.newsID = jsonnewes["term_id"] as! Int
                newsJson.newsCount = jsonnewes["count"] as! Int
                //print("News COUNT3 \(newsJson.newsCount)")
            }

            insertOrUpdate(newsJson)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если у каждой новости есть primaryKey(уникальный ID), то можно добавлять объект в realm таким образом:

```
try! realm.write {
    realm.add(newsJson, update: true)
}
```

Если объекта с таким primaryKey не существует в базе, то он добавится. Если он существует, то останется неизменным или обновит свои поля, если вдруг в конкретной новости что-то поменялось.